# Eliminating a git commit via push didn't work as expected

Tags: git

I have been working on my personal project (I'm the sole developer). I have branched out for the last two months. Now that I was trying to merge the branch back to master, I noticed that I had an unnecessary commit left on the master branch, that is causing a conflict. I thought it would be nice to remove it altogether rather than merging it and trying to resolve the conflicts.

I ended up reverting it at first and it looked ok. But I thought why not just eliminating both the `revert` and the previous actual commit entirely from the history.

So I did this: `git push -f origin HEAD^:master`

However when I do a git log, I still can see the old commit, only that origin/master has moved a step below.

```
commit 9b7a71ec22f45eb319aec18b47bc56405a50534f (HEAD -> master)
Date:   Sun Oct 7 19:39:53 2018 +0330

    Revert "changes due to new laptop"

    This reverts commit d267cfa4eea1ac54700850ff056f0a86be79730d.

commit d267cfa4eea1ac54700850ff056f0a86be79730d (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Date:   Wed Aug 1 07:26:53 2018 +0100

    changes due to new laptop

commit ca930bf6ea64ba73a429c371b37654c5d5acc2eb
Date:   Sat Jul 28 12:31:04 2018 +0100

    completed more tests
```

Before I do more of a mess, I thought I would ask here some git experts. How can I save this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your `origin/master` points to the commit you want, `d267cfa`. Now you can discard the local `master` commit, `9b7a71ec` by being on the `master` branch and doing:

`git reset --hard origin/master`

That will make your `master` point to `origin/master`. Be sure that this is what you want - doing `git reset --hard` is one of the few ways to lose commits permanently in git.

Answer (score 0):

You were on master @ d267cfa, you reverted that commit thus you master moved @ 9b7a71e;

you pushed HEAD^ (whuch is then d267cfa) on the remote master, but did not removed it locally nor "pulled", thus everything is normal IMHO.

I you really want your master to point @ca930bf6ea64ba73a do this:

(Assuming you do not have unstage stuff.)

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard ca930bf6ea64ba73a
git push -f origin master:master
```

and that should be ok